# Best way to generate report output C#

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, reporting

I currently have a DataGridView bound to a LIST that contains 4 fields. The first field contains a credit card type.

I would like to group the output by the type of card (ordered by date) and then provide subtotals for the total charges for each card type.

I am fairly confident I should be able to figure out how to sort the records by Credit Card Type and then by date however I am not certain how I would display subtotals utilizing a DataGridView especially if it is bound to that particular LIST.

Is there a better way to go about what I am trying to accomplish? (i.e. should I be printing the output to a RichTextBox to have more control over the output?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the ReportViewer control that is included is Visual Studio. The following resource site provides good information for embedding reports into your application:

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

The ReportViewer control supports rendering SQL Server Reports that can be designed using a number of WYSIWYG tools including Visual Studio.  These reports are very robust and include many features in addition to the grouping and subtotal features that you need.